# Does the android salesforce 1 app support any android intents?

Tags: android

Does the android salesforce 1 app support any android intents?
For accessing or manipulating data from other apps.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that there is any way to access/modify data via any intents.

The only interopability that appears to be available is via the certain URL schemes it supports, and these are to just open the app and show a specific record etc..

[As per the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000213748&language=en_US):

> This article describes URL schemes that are supported by the
>   Salesforce1 for iOS mobile application. A URL scheme allows a user to
>   launch the Salesforce1 app from a third party or web application. An
>   administrator or developer can customize a URL scheme to perform a
>   specific action when the Salesforce1 app launches. For example, if a
>   user receives an email about a feed post, you can create a link for
>   the user to tap to view the post in the Salesforce1app.
>
> ### Salesforce1 URL Scheme Format
>
> A request to the Salesforce1 URL scheme
>   follows this format:
>
> `<scheme_name>://sObject/<id>/<action>`
>
> Let’s break
>   down each parameter of the URL scheme format:
>
> - scheme_name: Supported
>     Salesforce1 scheme names.
> - sObject: Indicates a single instance of a
>     Salesforce object.
> - id: The unique single instance of a Salesforce
>     object. id lengths of 15 and 18 characters are supported.
> - action:
>     Supported URL scheme operations.
>
> ### Scheme Name
>
> Salesforce1 currently supports the following scheme_name parameters for URL schemes :
>
> - salesforce1://
>
> Actions These are the available action parameters for
>   URL schemes:
>
> - view: Navigates the user to the Salesforce1 app to view
>     a record in detail.
> - edit: Navigates the user to the Salesforce1 app
>     to the edit detail page of a record.
> - download: Download any version
>     of a file.
> - follow: Follow users to see their posts, comments, and
>     likes in your feed.

There's more detail in the docs that I've included here but I think this is the pertinent part and gives a pretty good idea of what you can do.